# How to get new database default values back from Model#create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, uuid

Is there a way to get new database default values after create without a reload?

```
create_table :models do |t|
  t.uuid :token, default: 'uuid_generate_v4()'
end
```

The token doesn't come back after create.

```
model = Model.create()
model.token
# => nil
model.reload.token
# => "acff37c1-cb7e-4c85-9ebb-f4cd264f764b"
```

In SQL with `returning` keyword its possible.

```
insert into models (...) values (...) returning *;
```

Rails manages to come back with a new `id`, so how can I get all the new default values?

Comment: You probably have to write a raw SQL query to get all the values back. I'd recommend generating a UUID in a model callback.